# how can I run play framework with port=9001 under windows cmd not under play console?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Under Play console, I can type "run 9001" to run a server in port 9001.
But Under windows cmd,  When I type "play run 9001", it does not work.

Please help .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write exactly like this (with quotas)

```
play "run 9001"
```

you can also add other options (again quotas are important)

```
play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true "start 9003"
```

**Late edit:**

On Windows you can try such trick to avoid error message `9001"" was unexpected at this time`

```
play '-Dhttp.port=9004' 'run 9004'
```

or

```
play '-Dconfig.file=C:\apps\some-app\conf\other.conf' "run 9005"
```

Comment: Weird, maybe you have 9001 bussy ? try run on some higher port. Write more about the problem. What is that mean that 'doesn't work' ?

Comment: thx. About play "run 9001", I succeed on linux but failed on windows.

Comment: on windows, the error message was    9001"" was unexpected at this ti me

Comment: play "run 9001", works fine on Windows 7 powershell, playframework 2.2.X

Answer (score 2):

it seems that the following command will fail, at least on windows

```
>play "run 9001"
```

what works for me is to start the play console by just typing

```
>play
[app01] $run 9001
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command to run play on required port.

1. > play
2. > run port_no i.e. example:- run 8080