# Change plays default port doesn't work

Tags: playframework-2.0

When I'm on my mac I can start the server like this

```
activator start -Dhttp.port=9090
```

Now when I do this on the windows 2012 server I get that the command isn't valid.

How can I change the default port on Windows then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
play '-Dhttp.port=9090' 'start 9090'
```

or

```
activator '-Dhttp.port=9090' 'start 9090'
```

at least that was working some time ago, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11139985/1066240)

The behavior varies on exact Play version, anyway you need to test several versions (always with quotes) so finally you'll find the solution, unfortunately I haven't any Win machine to check latest Play now.

Comment: This gives me the input line is too long and then the syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Did you try it like this or replaced `play` by `activator` ? I'm using this : `activator -Dhttp.port=9090 start` and it works on both OS. Note that the command must be at the end